# Transform file content to an specific output in bash

Tags: bash, csv

I'm new to bash scripting, and I am trying to transform a file that:

- Is a CSV
- Has random line jumps that break the format (bad inputs from user in CSV)

The outcome needs to be a processed file that separates lines correctly (lines of a set # of elements/columns), removing the random jumps.

My first aproach was to remove all the line jumps by using

```
variable=$(cat $1)
tr -d "\n" $variable > $variable
```

and then though of reading char by char looking for ',' with a counter, and adding a line jump after every set number of them were found. When trying to do this, I found info on `while IFS= read` and tried the following:

```
while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 <<< $variable; do

    echo "$col1" "$col2" "$col3" "$col4" '\n'

done
```

I'm clearly missing something there (I even believe the *while* loop should already remove the line jumps, please correct me about it) and I am not sure how to keep going about it. I am not looking for a bunch of code that does the job, but trying to find someone here who could point me towards the right direction (maybe I'm not understanding IFS, or I need to process something prior to that step... whatever it could be).

Thanks in advance.

edit: I removed the line jump I was adding in the echo and it now prints 
col1 col2 col3 col4
and never ends, so I am clearly not being able to link each element from the file to the variables before printing.

Comment: instead of '\n' write "\n"

Comment: I just did change the single ' ' in the \n and started printing "col1 col2 col3 col4 \n" so I removed the added line jump completely. Added an edit about it in the main post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

instead of  `echo "$col1" "$col2" "$col3" "$col4" '\n'`

just write this

```
 echo -e "$col1 $col2 $col3 $col4 \n"
```

Actually the problem isn't with the `shell`, is `echo` command itself, and the lack of double quotes around the variable interpolation. You can try using `echo -e` but that isn't supported on all platforms, and one of the reasons `printf` is now recommended for portability.

You can also try and insert the newline directly into your shell script (if a script is what you're writing) so it looks like...

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "this is for
test"
#EOF
```

or equivalently

```
#!/bin/sh
string="this is for
test"
echo "$string"  
# note double quotes!
```

good luck